# When does Peter's confession in John 6:69 occur relative to that in Matthew 16:16?

Tags: john, matthew

The chronology of John's Gospel often seems a bit difficult to follow. In the sixth chapter, Peter makes this declaration:

> **John 6:69**: "We have believed and have come to know that **You are the Holy One of God**" (emphasis added).

This, in contrast to that of Matthew's Gospel:

> **Matthew 16:16-17**: "Simon Peter answered, '**You are the Christ, the Son of the living God**.' <sup>17</sup>And Jesus said to him, 'Blessed are you, Simon Barjona, because flesh and blood did not reveal this to you, but My Father who is in heaven'" (emphasis added).

Are these two entirely separate instances? Or, might John 6:69 be chronologically similar to Peter's confession in Matthew 16:16?

Answer (score 4):

### Same Confession, different context

This is one of the cases where John differs most from the Synoptics which, in spite of their differences ([Matt 16:13-20](http://classic.net.bible.org/passage.php?search=Matt%2016:13-20&passage=matt%2016:13-20#n3); [Mark 8:27-30](http://classic.net.bible.org/passage.php?search=Mark%208:27-30&passage=mark%208:27-30); [Luke 9:18-22](http://classic.net.bible.org/passage.php?search=Luke%209:18-22&passage=luke%209:18-22)), have these elements in common (which we don't find in John):

- The location (Caesarea Philippi), not mentioned by Luke, though;
- Jesus' question on peoples' opinion, “Who do people say that the Son
  of Man is [I am]?”
- The answer of the disciples (John the Baptist, Elijah, Jeremiah one
  of the prophets - and variants thereof)
- Jesus' question on the disciples' opinion (“But who do you say that I
  am?”)
- Peter's answer on behalf of the twelve (“You are the Christ, the Son of the living God.” - with variants in Mark and Luke)
- Jesus' approval of Peter (only in Matthew)
- The much disputed sentence of Jesus, "And I tell you that you are Peter, and on this rock I will build my church, etc." - only in Matthew
- Jesus' warning to keep secrecy
- Jesus prediction of his suffering, rejection, killing and resurrection (only Luke)

The core of Peter's confession in John is this verse:

> We have come to believe and to know that you are the Holy One of God!”
> ([John 6:69](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=John%206:69&book=john&chapter=6&verse=69))

It is worth reproducing here the footnotes appended by NET Bible at the end of the verse:

> <sup>3</sup>**tc** The witnesses display a bewildering array of
> variants here. Instead of “the Holy One of God” (ὁ ἅγιος τοῦ θεοῦ, *ho
> hagios tou theou*, Tertullian has ὁ Χριστός (*ho Christos*, “the
> Christ”); C3 Θ* Ë1 33 565 lat read ὁ Χριστὸς ὁ υἱὸς τοῦ θεοῦ (ho
> Christos ho uios tou theou, “the Christ, the Son of God”); two
> versional witnesses (b syc) have ὁ υἱὸς τοῦ θεοῦ (“the Son of God”);
> the Byzantine text as well as many others (Ψ 0250 Ë13 33 Ï) read ὁ
> Χριστὸς ὁ υἱὸς τοῦ θεοῦ τοῦ ζῶντος (ho Christos ho uios tou theou ho
> zontos, “the Christ, the Son of the living God”); and Ì66 as well as a
> few versions have ὁ Χριστὸς ὁ ἅγιος τοῦ θεοῦ (“the Christ, the Holy
> One of God”). The reading ὁ ἅγιος τοῦ θεοῦ is, however, well supported
> by Ì75 א B C* D L W as well as versional witnesses. It appears that
> Peter’s confession in the Synoptic Gospels (especially [Matt
> 16:16](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Matt%2016:16&book=matt&chapter=16&verse=16)) supplied the motivation for the variations. Although the
> witnesses in [Matt 16:16](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Matt%2016:16&book=matt&chapter=16&verse=16); [Mark 8:29](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Mark%208:29&book=mark&chapter=8&verse=29); and [Luke 9:20](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Luke%209:20&book=luke&chapter=9&verse=20) vary
> considerably, the readings are all intra-synoptic, that is, they do
> not pull in “the Holy One of God” but reflect various permutations of
> “Christ”/“Christ of God”/“Christ, the Son of God”/“Christ, the Son of
> the living God.” The wording “the Holy One of God” (without “Christ”)
> in important witnesses here is thus unique among Peter’s confessions,
> and best explains the rise of the other readings.
>
> **sn** You have the words of eternal life…you are the Holy One of God! In contrast to the response of some of his disciples, here is the
> response of the twelve, whom Jesus then questioned concerning their
> loyalty to him. This was the big test, and the twelve, with Peter as
> spokesman, passed with flying colors. The confession here differs
> considerably from the synoptic accounts (Matt 16:16, Mark 8:29, and
> Luke 9:20) and concerns directly the disciples’ personal loyalty to
> Jesus, in contrast to those other disciples who had deserted him
> ([John 6:66](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=John%206:66&book=john&chapter=6&verse=66)).

**Conclusion**

In spite of the absence of many of the elements that are present in the Synoptics, the one we find in John 6:69 is essentially the same confession of Peter's that we find in Matthew.

The expression "the Holy One of God", far from being unique to the Gospel of John, is even used by Peter, speaking of Jesus, in Acts:

> But you rejected the Holy and Righteous One and asked that a man who
> was a murderer be released to you. ([Acts 3:14](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Acts%203:14&book=acts&chapter=3&verse=14))

Comment: +1 Very interesting on the textual variants for John 6:69.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is best answered by consulting a [Gospel Harmony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_harmony).  I consulted four of them, but the result is rather different.

##### Resources used

1. Two are based on the work started by John A. Broadus culminating in his own Harmony of the Gospels published in 1893, and thus offer similar chronologies.

   - [A Harmony of the Gospels](https://archive.org/details/harmonyofgospels00robeuoft/page/ii/mode/2up) (1923) by A. T. Robertson
   - [Harmony of the Gospels](https://www.amazon.ca/Hcsb-Harmony-Gospels-Steven-Cox/dp/0805494448) (2006) by Steven Cox and Kendell Easley
2. [The Four-Fold Gospel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1936341018) (1914) by J.W. McGarvey, LL.D. and Philip Y. Pendleton, A.B.
3. [Synopsis of the Four Gospels](https://www.logos.com/product/8890/synopsis-of-the-four-gospels) by Kurt Aland (2009).
4. [NET Bible Synopsis of the Four Gospels](https://bible.org/assets/pdf/White_ntsynopsis.pdf) (2009) by Gregory White (ed.) synthesized Kurt Aland's harmony + [Eusebian Canons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eusebian_Canons) + NET Bible texts into a table format in neatly typeset pages.  He also added  maps and various lists in the Appendix.

##### What the resources say about the 2 pericopes

1. In the harmonies based on Broadus's work, John 6:69 appears in a ***separate, earlier event toward the beginning of Jesus's ministry*** in *Part VIII: The Special Training of the Twelve in Districts around Galilee.*
2. In McGarvey's harmony, John 6:69 also appears in a **separate, earlier event, but toward the latter end of Jesus's ministry**:

   - John 6:22-71 is at the end of Part 5 (From Second Passover until Third) Chapter 64 (Discourse on Spiritual Food and True Discipleship. Peter's Confession)
   - Matt 16:13-20 is in Part 6 (From the Third Passover until Our Lord's Arrival at Bethany) Chapter 70 (Third Withdrawal from Herod's Territory)
3. In Kurt Aland's harmony, **both pericopes are in the same entry**: # 158 (Peter's Confession).

   - See #158 in the synopsis outline [here](http://www4.westminster.edu/staff/nak/courses/documents/Aland%20periocopes%20sum.pdf).
   - See #158 in page 127 of [Gregory White's book](https://bible.org/assets/pdf/White_ntsynopsis.pdf)

##### Outline from Broadus's harmony

To give you a sense on where the 2 events occur in the Broadus's harmony, please see the following outline with your 2 events **bolded**:

- Part I: The Sources of the Gospels
- Part II: The Pre-existent State of Christ and His Incarnation
- Part III: The Two Genealogies in Matthew and Luke
- Part IV: The Birth and Childhood of the Baptist and of Jesus
- Part V: The Beginning of the Baptist's Ministry
- Part VI: The Beginning of Christ's Public Ministry
- Part VII: The Great Galilean Ministry
- Part VIII: The Special Training of the Twelve in Districts around Galilee

  | § | Title | Matt | Mark | Luke | John |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 72 | Feeding 5,000 | 14:13-21 | 6:30-44 | 9:10-17 | 6:1-13 |
  | 73 | Jesus Sends the Disciples On | 14:22-23 | 6:45-46 |  | 6:14-15 |
  | 74 | Walking on the Water | 14:24-33 | 6:47-52 |  | 6:16-21 |
  | 75 | Miraculous Healings | 14:34-36 | 6:53-56 |  |  |
  | **76** | **The Bread of Life** |  |  |  | **6:22-71** |
  | 77 | The Tradition of the Elders | 15:1-20 | 7:1-23 |  | 7:1 |
  | 78 | A Gentile Mother's Faith | 15:21-28 | 7:24-30 |  |  |
  | 79 | Jesus Does Everything Well; Feeds 4,000 | 15:29-38 | 7:31-8:9 |  |  |
  | 80 | The Sign of Jonah | 15:39-16:4 | 8:10-12 |  |  |
  | 81 | The Yeast of the Pharisees and the Sadducees | 16:5-12 | 8:13-26 |  |  |
  | **82** | **Peter's Confession of the Messiah** | **16:13-20** | 8:27-30 | 9:18-21 |  |
  | 83 | Jesus Foretells His Death and Resurrection | 16:21-26 | 8:31-37 | 9:22-25 |  |
  | 84 | Public Commitment to the Son of Man | 16:27-28 | 8:34-9:1 |  |  |
  | 85 | The Transfiguration | 17:1-8 | 9:2-8 | 9:28-36a |  |
  | 86 | The Disciples' Puzzlement Concerning Elijah and the Resurrection | 17:9-13 | 9:9-13 | 9:36b |  |
  | 87 | The Power of Faith over a Demon | 17:14-21 | 9:14-29 | 9:37-43a |  |
  | 88 | Jesus' Second Prediction of His Death | 17:22-23 | 9:30-32 | 9:43b-45 |  |
  | 89 | Paying the Temple Tax | 17:23-27 |  |  |  |
  | 90 | Who Is the Greatest | 18:1-5 | 9:33-37 | 9:46-48 |  |
  | 91 | Warnings from Jesus | 18:6-14 | 9:38-50 | 9:49-50 |  |
  | 92 | Restoration and Forgiveness | 18:15-35 |  |  |  |
  | 93 | Following Jesus | 8:18-22 |  | 9:57-62 |  |
  | 94 | The Unbelief of Jesus' Brothers |  |  |  | 7:2-9 |
  | 95 | The Journey to Jerusalem |  |  | 9:51-56 | 7:10 |
- Part IX: The Later Judean Ministry
- Part X: The Later Perean Ministry
- Part XI: The Last Public Ministry in Jerusalem
- Part XII: In the Shadow with Jesus
- Part XIII: The Arrest, Trial, Crucifixion, and Burial of Jesus
- Part XIV: The Resurrection, Appearances, and Ascension of Christ

Comment: +1 for referring the the Harmonies. Interestingly, Matthew's "Simon Peter answered, 'You are **the Christ, the Son of the living God.**'" in Mark is "Peter answered, “You are **the Christ**.”" and in Luke is "Peter answered, “**The Christ of God**.”"

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Thank you! My congregation is just now beginning a study in John, and I've often been puzzled by the chronology relative to the other Gospels (as my recent questions probably suggest). Many thanks also for the references. +1.

Comment: I added 2 more resources.  Hope it helps.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Really interested in Aland's reasons for making them the same event.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Yes, unfortunately I haven't been able to obtain any introduction / preface / essays by Kurt Aland, or even 3rd party explanation of his synopsis yet.

Comment: @Xeno For what it's worth, here's [another harmony by Rick Aschmann](https://aschmann.net/BibleChronology/ChronologyOfTheFourGospels.pdf) similar to Pendelton's one.  He has notes and updates it as late as 2020.  Personally, I believe although the chronological backbone of each gospel is largely true, each evangelist shapes the narrative and the words in the dialog to suit a particular theological angle rather than prioritizing a precise news-article style chronicle.  Plus why does Peter's confession should happen only in 1 or 2 events?  As John 21:25 implied, there could have been more.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Right - even within Matthew itself, it appears all the disciples state Jesus is the Son of God prior to Peter's confession that Jesus is the Christ and Son of God (Matthew 14:33).

Comment: @GratefulDisciple These are very helpful; I appreciate your assistance. Unless you've already seen it, there an excellent commentary: *Why Four Gospels*, by Arthur W. Pink, Swengel, PA, 1921 [here](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/p/pink/gospels/cache/gospels.pdf), which offers some interesting insights into the unique dimensions of each.